# Python passing callback function in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, gurobi

I have to try to move from the non-class-based coding style into class-based coding style, but facing an issue. The optimize() function takes a callback function mycallback(). The code works perfectly fine in Non-class-based method, but when I moved it to class-based method, I got an error "mycallback() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)".

What is the right way to pass a callback function in the class-based method?

(A) Non-class-based method:

```
def mycallback(model, where):
    pass

model = Model()
model.optimize(mycallback)
```

(B) Class-based method:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()

    def solve(self):
        # Try method 1:
        self.model.optimize(self.mycallback())      <--- Error: mycallback() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
        # Try method 2:
        # self.model.optimize(self.mycallback)  <--- Error:  Callback argument must be a function

    def mycallback(self, model, where):     
        pass
```

While this is a problem regarding passing a callback function to Gurobi's (an optimization solver） built-in function, I believe it is a more general question on how to pass a callback function defined in a class to another function in Python.

---

Error For method 2:

```
   self.model.optimize(self.mycallback)  
   File "model.pxi", line 458, in gurobipy.Model.optimize      (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:34263)
   gurobipy.GurobiError: Callback argument must be a function
```

Looks like it is likely to be Gurobi API issue. Wonder if any Gurobi dev will response.

Comment: Why even have three parameters when all you do is `pass`

Comment: You don't need to call `self.mycallback()`, pass it as `self.model.optimize(self.mycallback)`.

Comment: Please post the full traceback error message you see when using method 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, `self.model.optimize(self.mycallback)` should work (note: no parens after `mycallback`).

It may fail if the code serializes the callable e.g., to be send via pipe/socket to another process (even on different machine):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

class C:
    def method(self, i):
        return "called", i

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(Pool().map(C().method, range(10)))
```

It works on recent Python versions where methods are pickable.

Or it may fail if `model.optimize()` has a bug and check for the exact function type instead of accepting any callable.

Answer (score 2):

This issue still persists in gurobi `9.1`. A simple workaround I found is to put the callback inside a method in your class, for instance:

```
def solve(self):
    self.model.update()
       def lazyCallback(model, where):
       ...
    self.model.optimize(lazyCallback)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you remove the callback from the object, then it works. You can use this as a work-around until you can get a callback working in-class. That is, call this line from within the class...

```
def solve(self):
    self.model.optimize(mycallback)
```

...to this function outside of the class.

```
def mycallback(self, model, where):     
    pass
```

Not elegant at all, but hopefully a developer chimes in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `self.mycallback` is that it is a *method* while Gurobi's [`optimize`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_optimize.html) method really expects a *function*.

There are multiple ways to make `self.mycallback` a function. Here are some examples:

One approach would be making `mycallback` a static method:

```
@staticmethod
def mycallback(model, where): 
    pass
```

Another would be wrapping the method into a function as follows:

```
self.model.optimize(lambda model, where: self.mycallback(model, where))
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents solution:

```
import queue as Queue
class A:
    def start(self):
       Queue.listen(callback=received)

    @staticmethod
    def received(*args):
       print(args)
```

Queue is defined in another module/file.